# Interlinking in pages from Admin backend wordpress 3.1

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I want to do interlinking within wordpress pages and say my URL is www.test.com for example and i have www.test.com/p1 www.test.com/p2 and www.test.com/p3 pages and I want to add p1 and p2 links in p3 from admin side.. right now, I just insert  and same for p2.. but if my permanlink changes than i need to change content again.. Is there any solution to this.. so I can able to insert just ID of page with  and it will convert it automatically to link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shortcode api to generate links with post-ids. 
When you add following code into your function.php

```
add_shortcode('permalink', 'permlink_replace_func');

function permlink_replace_func($atts){

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '',
        'lable' => 'link'
    ), $atts));

    $permpost = get_post($id);
    $html = '<a href="'.get_permalink($id).'" >';

    if ($lable==null) {
        $html .= $permpost->post_title;
    } else {
        $html .= $lable;
    }

    $html .= '</a>';

    return $html; 
 }
```

you can enter a string like `[permalink id ="8" lable="hallo world"]` in the content area of a post to get a link to another post per id.

More information about shortcodes you can find at the [WordPress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).